# How to achieve animation effect in wowza graphical overlays

Tags: wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am using Wowza Media System for live streaming. I want to display animated overlays on streaming. But animated image not supported in overlay. I am using set of jpg/png images for animation effect. On each frame, I change tje overlay image by using

```
mainImage.addOverlayImage(OverlayImg,0,0);
```

But this function add new image and previous image still there in memory, so memory usage reaches 100%. Is there any other way to this. I started by using this link [Add Graphical Overlay](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?432-How-to-add-graphic-overlays-to-live-streams-with-Wowza-Transcoder).